# Tokenize text with both American and English words

Tags: text-mining, nltk, text-filter

I need to tokenize a corpus of abstracts from an international conference. The abstracts are usually American English but sometimes British English.

Consequently, I get 2 tokens for “organization” and “organisation” or “color” and “colour”.
Examples : https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/spelling/british-and-spelling

Do you know a (python) library converting “British English” to “American English” (or vis versa) ?

I would be happy to that ... (but I am french and my english is not soo good)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Grouping related tokens is called [text normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_normalization).

There is not an established Python package that does this. You could create a [custom dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42329766/python-nlp-british-english-vs-american-english) or write [a function to rewrite the tokens](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html).

Comment: Thanks. I know I can make a function and what text normalization is. 
Just wanted to know if there is a established solution since the issue seems quite common. [This dictionnary is a good start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42329766/python-nlp-british-english-vs-american-english). Thanks.